# protect opencart payment callback function from direct access

Tags: php, opencart

i have coded a extension for a Frazy IPG (this ia local payment gateway, not famous at all). In their payment gateway we need to pass the values to their server and they encrypt it and send it to MIGS and when the transaction is success or failed it returns to the my site with the status.

the status values are added to the url when its redirected to my site

if success

```
index.php?route=payment/frazyiph/callback/&?status=success&message=transaction_success
```

if failed

```
index.php?route=payment/frazyiph/callback/&?status=failed&message=invalid_card
```

these are the only values returned after the payment. so i capture the status and the message from the url and update the database accordingly.

the problem im having is when a person adds a product and directly pastes the success url

```
index.php?route=payment/frazyiph/callback/&?status=success&message=transaction_success
```

it updates as the payment has been made. so i tried capturing the order_id and checking its not empty and update accordingly. The problem was when a person selects to pay at the IPG and cancelled it returns to my page saying the payment is cancelled. and then if someone pastes the success url it updates as the user has paid because the order id has been generated.

is there a way to protect the callback function and make sure the users are redirected from the IPG to my site to update the order and not just typed the url in the address bar?

Comment: Either it is a really stupid payment gateway or there is a mistake in implementation. The response (callback) from the payment gateway should be also encrypted while containing the order_id (or other unique identifier You can identify the order with) so that You can set the status of the payment to paid (if success) or leave it pending (on error). If it is true that payment gateway can only access the callback URL with `status=success` or `status=failed` and provides only some transaction message and nothing else, this is really a **bad** payment gateway...

Comment: yeh exactly...Its too basic, but i found a way to overcome it. i encrypted the data and added it into a session and compared it. So far it works great..

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand you, this is the third question you make for a payment module you are developing and thus far i have tried to assist you in each of them, but till now i am not even aware if i helped you, although i see you continue further ahead in the development, some feedback would be greatly appreciated...

And for your current question there is a way, you need to check the headers with php variables `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` or some other `$_SERVER['']` variable should give the necessary information so you can specify that only data that come from IPG are the ones you will accept.

Comment: sorry mate.. this is the 2nd payment gateway im tryning to integrate. the gateway providers over here do not have methods to integrate with carts. They are simply hosted forms. the one i tried before didnt work. i tried my best but failed. This one has 90% workable with my cart

Comment: i tried the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` when it redirects from the payment page to my site after completion, the referrer holds no value.. its empty.. any idea why?

Comment: What i meant is you post question really good ones but on all 2 questions you did not accept any answers, and i do not know if i actually helped you with them... Try and var_dump($_SERVER); exit; and see which of the variables is right for you, and the one you need. also http_refer may be empty in many cases, this depends on the server.

Comment: did a dump.. but it doesn't give the details about the referrer. None of the details can be used to validate the transaction :(

Comment: In that case you should check what data IPG returns on callback and how they return them, for example if they return a hashed code of the transaction details with sha1 you should use that as a validator, as a psyment gateway there should be some data that are unique, if you list me the returned data, i could guide you from there.

Comment: That's is this crappy IPG simply returns a only a flag and a status message. im trying to figure away to validate the transaction :(

Comment: If you are sure there is no variable returned, that you can call unique and the return back to you, then what you got to do is implement a dual authentication system, they should at least have that, and implement in the callback a curl that verifies payment with a server to server communication. Accept from that i am not familiar with any other method that could help you. Hope this solves your situation.

Comment: finally got it sorted. the ipg just returns only a status not any hashed codes. So wht i did was generate a random hashed string combined with the orderid and checked it against the callback. if its same updated the database and unset the session variable so it cannot be used again until a new one is generated. looks good so far. Thanks for your support mate :)